# Segmentation fault: why is it resolved in a mystery way?

Tags: function, segmentation-fault, fortran, subroutine

I have a problem with my Fortran code. 
So, here is two versions of my code:

```
      program test
      real*8 x1,x2,val,func,y
      x1 = 1.0
      x2 = 3.0
!     y = func(x1)

      call qgaus(func,x1,x2,val)
      write(*,*) 'answer', val

      end

      function func(x)
       real*8 func,x
       func = cos(x)
      end 

      SUBROUTINE qgaus(func,a,b,ss)
      REAL*8 a,b,ss,func
      EXTERNAL func
      INTEGER j
      REAL*8 dx,xm,xr,w(5),x(5)
      SAVE w,x
      DATA w/.2955242247,.2692667193,.2190863625,.1494513491,
     *.0666713443/
      DATA x/.1488743389,.4333953941,.6794095682,.8650633666,
     *.9739065285/
      xm=0.5*(b+a)
      xr=0.5*(b-a)
      ss=0
      do 11 j=1,5
        dx=xr*x(j)
        ss=ss+w(j)*(func(xm+dx)+func(xm-dx))

11    continue
      ss=xr*ss

      END
```

The second version is the same code but line 5 (`y = func(x1)`) is not commented.The first version shows me segmentation fault while the second program proceeds the calculations (integration of function) . To be specific, in the first case segmentation fault occurs when the subroutine calls the function ( I've checked it). Why does it happen? Why calling the function separately solves the problem? I am using GNU compiler. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use some really bad features of old Fortran. Learn to use `implicit none`, declare all arguments and preferably learn Fortran 90 and later standards, mainly modules and interfaces. Also learn to use compiler warnings, because `gfortran` can identify the error:

```
gfortran -fbacktrace -fcheck=all -Wall -g t1.f90 
t1.f90:8.12:

 call qgaus(func,x1,x2,val)
            1
Warning: Expected a procedure for argument 'func' at (1)
```

Subroutine `qgaus` needs a function as an argument.

When you do

```
real*8 x1,x2,val,func,y
  x1 = 1.0
  x2 = 3.0

 call qgaus(func,x1,x2,val)
```

then `func` is a real number, not a function, and the program must fail.

When you add

```
y = func(x1)
```

the compiler sees it is a function, because you are calling it that way. It will assume it is an external function.

The simplest fix is to declare `func` as `external`, but better is to read the first paragraph of my answer and properly define all variables and use explicit interfaces for procedures.